# Move Entire Row To Another Sheet Starting at a different column Based On Cell Value

Tags: excel, vba

This is my following code that works, but I need it to paste it starting in Column C. When changing Range("A" & J + 2) to Range("C" & J + 2) it will not work then. I know its something easy but I have yet to find a specific example.

Thanks

```
Sub Patrick()

    Dim xRg As Range
    Dim xCell As Range
    Dim i As Long
    Dim J As Long
    Dim K As Long
    
    
    i = Worksheets("Patrick").UsedRange.Rows.Count
    J = Worksheets("Sheet1").UsedRange.Rows.Count
    If J = 1 Then
       If Application.WorksheetFunction.CountA(Worksheets("Sheet1").UsedRange) = 0 Then J = 0
    End If
    Set xRg = Worksheets("Patrick").Range("A1:A" & i)
    On Error Resume Next
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    For K = 1 To xRg.Count
        If CStr(xRg(K).Value) = "Phone Call" Then
            xRg(K).EntireRow.Copy Destination:=Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A" & J + 2)
            J = J + 1
        End If
    Next
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
 End Sub
```

Comment: Hi Bryant J, welcome to Stack Overflow. Stack Overflow is for knowledge based questions regarding technologies and application. Your question is is implementational and doesn't provide the community  with any specific insights and knowledge. It is simply the indexing of a for loop. I'd suggest you spend some more time with a debugger understanding how the for loop and its indexing works. This is basic coding 101.

Comment: Jim, Not sure what you mean. Tim Williams answered my question down below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`xRg(K).EntireRow.Copy` copies a *whole row* - you can't paste that anywhere but the first column.

Use something more reasonable like

```
xRg(K).EntireRow.Columns("A:Z").Copy
```

or whatever will capture the data you have on your source sheet

Comment: Thank you this worked. I tried giving it the upvote, but wouldn't let me.

Comment: If it's working you can accept it as an answer by clicking the checkmark next to it - that tells anyone else coming along later there's an answer to your question.

Comment: Thanks! Got it Done.